# Error with soap requests on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, soap-client

I have a simple SOAP client application which works perfect.
But when I put its piece of code into other web project (tomcat 8.5), it doesn't work. 
It throws exception:

> 19-Oct-2017 11:10:48.019 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-10]
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post
>   SAAJ0008: Bad Response; Forbidden 
>   Ошибка при отправке сообщения SOAP-серверу:
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl:
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Bad response:
>   (403Forbidden     at
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:164)
>     at
>   ls.common.objects.SOAPMessageSender.callSoapWebService(SOAPMessageSender.java:72)
>     at
>   ls.webSite.common.servlets.cli_GetMKBClientByIIN.processRequests(cli_GetMKBClientByIIN.java:49)
>     at
>   common.servlets.prototypes.AbstractServlet.processRequest(AbstractServlet.java:369)
>     at
>   common.servlets.prototypes.AbstractServlet.doPost(AbstractServlet.java:503)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Bad response:
>   (403Forbidden     at
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:276)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:160)
>     ... 28 more

Why it doesn't work on web project? Is it problem with keystore? 
Here is example of my code:

```
public class InsuranceSOAPMessageCreator {

    public static SOAPMessage createSOAPMessageFromXML(String soapActionFull, String sourceXmlFile, Map<String, String> params)
            throws IOException, SOAPException {

        Path path  = Paths.get(sourceXmlFile);
        String xml = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path));

        MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();

        if(params != null){
            for(Map.Entry entry : params.entrySet()){
                xml = xml.replace("##$[" + entry.getKey().toString() + "]$##", entry.getValue().toString());
            }
        }

        SOAPMessage msg = mf.createMessage(new MimeHeaders(),
                new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));

        msg.getMimeHeaders().addHeader("SOAPAction", soapActionFull);

        return msg;
    }


}
```

---

```
public class SOAPMessageSender {

        private String nameSpaceURI;
        private String endpointUrl;
        private String trustStore;
        private String trustStorePassword;
        private String keyStore;
        private String keyStorePassword;
        private SOAPMessage soapResponse;

        public SOAPMessageSender(){
        }

        public SOAPMessageSender(String endpointUrl, String nameSpaceURI, String trustStore, String trustStorePassword,
                                 String keyStore, String keyStorePassword){

            this.nameSpaceURI = nameSpaceURI;
            this.keyStorePassword = keyStorePassword;
            this.keyStore = keyStore;
            this.trustStorePassword = trustStorePassword;
            this.trustStore = trustStore;
            this.endpointUrl = endpointUrl;
            setSystemProperties();
        }

        public void setSystemProperties(){
            System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");
            System.setProperty("com.ibm.ssl.performURLHostNameVerification", "true");

            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStore);
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustStorePassword);

            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStore);
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword",keyStorePassword);
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "jks");
        }

        public String callSoapWebService(String soapAction, String sourceXml, Map<String, String> params)  {

            try {

                SOAPConnectionFactory scf = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
                SOAPConnection sc = scf.createConnection();
                /*SOAPMessage requestMsg = createSOAPMessageFromXML(nameSpaceURI + "/" + soapAction,
                        sourceXml, params);*/
                //doTrustToCertificates();
                soapResponse = sc.call(InsuranceSOAPMessageCreator.createSOAPMessageFromXML(soapAction,
                        sourceXml, params), endpointUrl);

                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                soapResponse.writeTo(out);

                sc.close();

                return out.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Ошибка при отправке сообщения SOAP-серверу:" + endpointUrl);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        ... 

        public static void main(String[] args){
            //works fine here (on local run main method)
            Map <String, String> authenticationData = new HashMap<>();
            authenticationData.put("login", "user");
            authenticationData.put("password", "pass");

            SOAPMessageSender me = new SOAPMessageSender("https://somehost/someservice.asmx",
                    "https://someuri",
                    "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts",
                    "password",
                    "/path/to/mykey.jks",
                    "password");
            String resultXml = me.callSoapWebService("someaction",
                    "/path/to/AuthenticateUser.xml", authenticationData);
            System.out.println(resultXml);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is Solved. Tomcat just couldn't get jks file specified in System.setProperty()  and I solved it by using java.security.KeyStore object. Here is my added method:

```
public void loadKeyStoreAndDoTrustToCertificates(String ksFile, String ksPass, String tsAlgo) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream ksCert = new FileInputStream(ksFile);

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        ks.load(ksCert, ksPass.toCharArray());
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(tsAlgo);
        kmf.init(ks, ksPass.toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tsAlgo);
        tmf.init(ks);

        Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String urlHostName, SSLSession session) {
                if (!urlHostName.equalsIgnoreCase(session.getPeerHost())) {
                    System.out.println("Ошибка: URL хост '" + urlHostName + "' отличается SSL хоста'" + session.getPeerHost() + "'.");
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
    }
```